# displaying data related to a contact

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

I don't really know how to deal with the next issue :

So, I've a webbased application developped with ASP.NET MVC3, which is used to remember when an event is relayed to some people.

I've 3 tables

```
Contact
 id_contact
 name
 firstname
 ...

event
 id_event
 ...

transmission
 FK_id_event
 FK_id_firstname
 mailed (boolean)
 phoned (boolean)
```

For each event, I need to list all the contacts that are related to this event. And for each contact, I need to display 2 checkboxes that have to be checked if the contact has been called or mailed.

```
    '
    ' GET: /Event/Details/5

    Function Details(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        Dim event As event = db.event.Single(Function(o) o.idOpportunite = id)

        Dim contacts = (From a In db.contact, b In db.transmission
                       Where a.id_Contact = b.FK_id_contact And b.FK_id_event = id
                       Select a)
        Dim transmission = (From a In contacts, b In db.transmission
                        Where a.id_Contact = b.FK_trans_cont
                        Select b)

        Dim model = New EventDetails With {
            .event= event,
            .Contacts = contacts,
            .TransOpp = transopp
            }

        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

I don't know if the "transmission" part of the code is good or not.

Here in the view, this is were I display the contacts

```
        @For Each contact In Model.contacts
            @<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(contact.name + " " + contact.firstname , "Details", New With {.id = contact.idContact})
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(contact.phone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.mail)*@
                    <a href=mailto:@contact.mail>@Html.Raw(contact.mail)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                   ***My checkboxes should be here***
                </td>
            </tr>
        Next
```

So, my question is, what should I do to display those checkboxes?

(sorry if I'm not understandable, I'm not a native english speaker. Don't hesitate to edit my english mistakes (or the title which is not a great one)).

With the help of Yasser, I've done this :

```
                    @code
                    Dim mail As Boolean = (From a In Model.Event
                    Where a.FK_id_contact = contact.idContact And a.FK_id_event = Model.Opportunite.idOpportunite
                    Select a.mailed)

                    End Code
```

However, I get an error : 
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Boolean)' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.

Comment: add .FirstOrDefault() to your query like, 
Dim mail As Boolean = (From a In Model.Event
                    Where a.FK_id_contact = contact.idContact And a.FK_id_event = Model.Opportunite.idOpportunite
                    Select a.mailed).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: It tells me that I have already an open DataReader associated with this connection that must be closed first. I don't see were I can have an open connexion. I had already had that kind of error. Putting a "tolist" after the linq query had solved the problem. Here, it doesn't do anything :-(

Comment: I've put a tolist() after all the queries of the controller, and it solved the problem. I just don't know why. Thx, the checkboxes are now displayed, I'll use an ajax query to update the changes of the checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that should help

```
 @{ 
 bool isMailed =  // set values;
 bool isPhoned = // set values
  }
@Html.CheckBox("mailed ", isMailed );
@Html.CheckBox("phoned", isPhoned );
```

Comment: Your " // set values;" is the problem I have. How to set those values? how to catch those values in the view from the DB?

Comment: I've been a little bit further, but I've had an error that I don't really know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

In your ContactViewModel you can have two properties

```
bool isMailed ;
bool isPhoned ;
```

Then you can query the database from your controller before you bind the viewmodel the view and set those parameters. For example if you are showing data for contact id = 1 and event id = 2, you can query the database table transmissions and find whether you have called or mailed before and update the variable in ContactViewModel.

then in your view you can bind the values to the checkbox as follows

```
@Html.CheckBox("mailed ", contact.isMailed );
@Html.CheckBox("phoned", contact.isPhoned );
```

if you want to update the mailed or phoned in the database you can do it using the above ViewModel by submitting data to the controller. from controller you can find what is the Event_Id, Contact_Id and mailed or phoned , then you can update the database accordingly

Comment: Thx for your support. I don't know if your answer is better than the one just above, but the first one worked, and I'll use this one.